# What standard is this RJ45 connector using?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I was expecting to see T568A/B but this is neither. What is this? It's 1. Brown 2. Green stripe 3. Orange Stripe 4. Blue 5. Blue Stripe 6. Orange 7. Green 8. Brown Stripe. I've wired the other side where this wire comes out of the wall to T568B, but this is what my wire tester shows.

[image: first 4 pins]
[image: wire tester result]
[image: last 4 pins]

Edit:

**Update**
Based on the comments on this post I do believe this was originally intended for telephone lines. I switched the wiring on the top port to be T568A and I did the same for where it comes out of the wall on the other side. Now my wire tool shows this, but I still can't connect to Ethernet. I get constant connecting/disconnecting errors on both a windows and linux pc.

[image]

Edit:
**Update**

ifconfig

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ceeb:e1d3:c921:a67  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:5e:d3:d5:c5:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 115  bytes 11018 (11.0 KB)
        RX errors 317  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 317
        TX packets 519  bytes 77177 (77.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 327
        device memory 0x53200000-532fffff
```

journalctl -u NetworkManager

```
May 29 02:28:29 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341709.2321] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: '>
May 29 02:28:29 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341709.2584] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.1757] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.1761] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state>
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.1773] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (e66e6c53-8fde-3a56-b3bb-57ee5f0f0c8c)
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.1782] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (e66e6c53-8fde-3a56-b3bb-57ee5f>
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.1785] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.2622] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.2627] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 29 02:28:56 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341736.2630] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 29 02:28:58 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341738.8633] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
May 29 02:29:08 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341748.4998] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: '>
May 29 02:29:08 mint-pc NetworkManager[842]: <info>  [1685341748.5265] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
```

ethtool enp3s0

```
Settings for enp3s0:
    Supported ports: [  ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
                            2500baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
                            2500baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: off (auto)
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

Edit:
This is what is plugged into the wall https://www.leviton.com/en/products/41108-rw8

Comment: At first glance that doesn't look "standard" to me at all – the 'brown' is especially confusing. Do you have photos from the other side? Is there only one cable coming in to this box? Are you _sure_ this was actually wired for Ethernet and not for something else? (My first thought was that this was wired for three analog-telephone lines, but looking closely, there seem to be more cables, so if it's supposed to be Ethernet I would just call it "wired incompetently". Did they really need to un-twist that much cable?)

Comment: (After actually reading the list of colors in the post, it does smell a bit like "Ethernet wired by someone who only ever worked with telephone lines", though I haven't worked with telephone lines myself so I can't really say.)

Comment: @user1686 I can't say with 100% certainty because these lines were put in before I was here. However, I can make out "Cat5e" on both ends of the cable

Comment: @user1686 and to answer your question, yes each jack is a separate  cat5e cable.

Comment: Cat5e can be used for many things (telephone lines included), it is not *inherently* an Ethernet cable. Those stickers look weird (two alternatives and they only differ in where the stripe goes on brown?), but if the numbers correspond to pins then it definitely rules out any kind of Ethernet wiring standard – Ethernet _would not_ like having 1/2 or 7/8 split across different pairs, no matter the color scheme. I'm still guessing "telephone".

Comment: for 10/100mbit you'd connect 1,2,3,6 - the fact that it appears 1,2,4,5 are connected suggests this was not intended to carry ethernet at all - 4,5 does suggest something to do with telephone

Comment: @user1686 I've rewired both sides to T568A and now can see that 1,2,3,4,5,6 match but 7 and 8 are still open according to my wire tester. I don't know what would cause that

Comment: i am suspicious that there is a cable somewhere in the walls joining these two before it comes out in the other room and that connection is missing pins 7/8. I don't know why internet wouldn't work at least at 100Mb even without pins 7/8 though.

Comment: Hmm, wait a moment – if there are *three* cables on this end, do you also have three matching cables coming out in the other room? Or do you only have one cable coming out? If they're all spliced into one (very likely for analog telephone), the 4-way splice will _definitely_ make Ethernet not work at all; it has to be one-to-one.

Comment: @user1686 each of the 'three' cables come out into 3 different rooms. I don't know if there is any splicing but it's possible. However on my computer I can see that ifconfig is getting some real errors and the switch is lighting up for a brief moment every now and again showing a 10Mb connection.